# Is the pigpio install script corrupt?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, blynk

Im making a doorlock using a raspberry pi, and blynk. When i try to do sudo npm install in the directory, I get this: "npm ERR! Failed at the pigpio@0.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above."
BTW, i am using this:
https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smartphone-Doorlock

I also tried to go on without pigpio, but it seems like the module pigpio is necceseary.

As asked by Jason(Thank You :D) here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/3YHyvp3e `0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v10.0.0
4 verbose npm-session bcd5a4f2650522e3
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall test-blynk@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle test-blynk@1.0.0~preinstall: test-blynk@1.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 166ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 5ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 163ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 201ms
18 timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 427ms
19 silly currentTree test-blynk@1.0.0
20 silly idealTree test-blynk@1.0.0
20 silly idealTree ├── bindings@1.3.1
20 silly idealTree ├── blynk-library@0.5.1
20 silly idealTree ├── epoll@1.0.2
20 silly idealTree ├── nan@2.8.0
20 silly idealTree ├── onoff@1.2.0
20 silly idealTree └─┬ pigpio@0.4.0
20 silly idealTree   ├── bindings@1.2.1
20 silly idealTree   └── nan@2.4.0
21 silly install generateActionsToTake
22 timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 98ms
23 silly diffTrees action count 8
24 silly diffTrees add bindings@1.3.1
25 silly diffTrees add nan@2.8.0
26 silly diffTrees add epoll@1.0.2
27 silly diffTrees add bindings@1.2.1
28 silly diffTrees add nan@2.4.0
29 silly diffTrees add blynk-library@0.5.1
30 silly diffTrees add onoff@1.2.0
31 silly diffTrees add pigpio@0.4.0
32 silly decomposeActions action count 64
33 silly decomposeActions fetch bindings@1.3.1
34 silly decomposeActions extract bindings@1.3.1
35 silly decomposeActions preinstall bindings@1.3.1
36 silly decomposeActions build bindings@1.3.1
37 silly decomposeActions install bindings@1.3.1
38 silly decomposeActions postinstall bindings@1.3.1
39 silly decomposeActions finalize bindings@1.3.1
40 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json bindings@1.3.1
41 silly decomposeActions fetch nan@2.8.0
42 silly decomposeActions extract nan@2.8.0
43 silly decomposeActions preinstall nan@2.8.0
44 silly decomposeActions build nan@2.8.0
45 silly decomposeActions install nan@2.8.0
46 silly decomposeActions postinstall nan@2.8.0
47 silly decomposeActions finalize nan@2.8.0
48 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json nan@2.8.0
49 silly decomposeActions fetch epoll@1.0.2
50 silly decomposeActions extract epoll@1.0.2
51 silly decomposeActions preinstall epoll@1.0.2
52 silly decomposeActions build epoll@1.0.2
53 silly decomposeActions install epoll@1.0.2
54 silly decomposeActions postinstall epoll@1.0.2
55 silly decomposeActions finalize epoll@1.0.2
56 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json epoll@1.0.2
57 silly decomposeActions fetch bindings@1.2.1
58 silly decomposeActions extract bindings@1.2.1
59 silly decomposeActions preinstall bindings@1.2.1
60 silly decomposeActions build bindings@1.2.1
61 silly decomposeActions install bindings@1.2.1
62 silly decomposeActions postinstall bindings@1.2.1
63 silly decomposeActions finalize bindings@1.2.1
64 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json bindings@1.2.1
65 silly decomposeActions fetch nan@2.4.0
66 silly decomposeActions extract nan@2.4.0
67 silly decomposeActions preinstall nan@2.4.0
68 silly decomposeActions build nan@2.4.0
69 silly decomposeActions install nan@2.4.0
70 silly decomposeActions postinstall nan@2.4.0
71 silly decomposeActions finalize nan@2.4.0
72 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json nan@2.4.0
73 silly decomposeActions fetch blynk-library@0.5.1
74 silly decomposeActions extract blynk-library@0.5.1
75 silly decomposeActions preinstall blynk-library@0.5.1
76 silly decomposeActions build blynk-library@0.5.1
77 silly decomposeActions install blynk-library@0.5.1
78 silly decomposeActions postinstall blynk-library@0.5.1
79 silly decomposeActions finalize blynk-library@0.5.1
80 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json blynk-library@0.5.1
81 silly decomposeActions fetch onoff@1.2.0
82 silly decomposeActions extract onoff@1.2.0
83 silly decomposeActions preinstall onoff@1.2.0
84 silly decomposeActions build onoff@1.2.0
85 silly decomposeActions install onoff@1.2.0
86 silly decomposeActions postinstall onoff@1.2.0
87 silly decomposeActions finalize onoff@1.2.0
88 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json onoff@1.2.0
89 silly decomposeActions fetch pigpio@0.4.0
90 silly decomposeActions extract pigpio@0.4.0
91 silly decomposeActions preinstall pigpio@0.4.0
92 silly decomposeActions build pigpio@0.4.0
93 silly decomposeActions install pigpio@0.4.0
94 silly decomposeActions postinstall pigpio@0.4.0
95 silly decomposeActions finalize pigpio@0.4.0
96 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json pigpio@0.4.0
97 silly install executeActions
98 silly doSerial global-install 64
99 verbose correctMkdir /home/pi/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
100 verbose lock using /home/pi/.npm/_locks/staging-654f2c7af40241aa.lock for /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging
101 silly doParallel extract 8
102 silly extract bindings@1.3.1
103 silly extract nan@2.8.0
104 silly extract epoll@1.0.2
105 silly extract bindings@1.2.1
106 silly extract nan@2.4.0
107 silly extract blynk-library@0.5.1
108 silly extract onoff@1.2.0
109 silly extract pigpio@0.4.0
110 silly tarball trying bindings@1.3.1 by hash: sha512-i47mqjF9UbjxJhxGf+pZ6kSxrnI3wBLlnGI2ArWJ4r0VrvDS7ZYXkprq/pLaBWYq4GM0r4zdHY+NNRqEMU7uew==
111 silly tarball trying nan@2.8.0 by hash: sha1-7XFfP+neArV6XmJS2QqWZ14fCFo=
112 silly tarball trying epoll@1.0.2 by hash: sha512-3t2crZPej4v60YYvXE/pgJ62D4RZBd/UsEXsHd+H3xtDre0vO8aV9O+0ThIPlfZtHJ4vMPhz55fYK1j37rX9Ng==
113 silly tarball trying bindings@1.2.1 by hash: sha1-FK1hE4EtLTfXLme0ystLtyZQXxE=
114 silly tarball trying nan@2.4.0 by hash: sha1-+zxZ1F/k7/4hXwuJD4rfbrMtIjI=
115 silly tarball trying blynk-library@0.5.1 by hash: sha512-YR5aNsNF0Atny/VGjz46kluImM8zPidLbwaVj8Peuxywro7VKi4QvSW2u5KiwhtsqqSWNHtdUXJhVbOjfchDiw==
116 silly tarball trying onoff@1.2.0 by hash: sha512-o41qBIIs6agXRjryGBIJpq1xour69VDBfROf3IX+wiwutIowPZDcjTRCqFo+HYleiQngO1wfNqHWpjm0l0oYwQ==
117 silly tarball trying pigpio@0.4.0 by hash: sha1-EfvLRReYDKG4JS6+Iffbb36mVbk=
118 silly tarball no local data for bindings@1.3.1. Extracting by manifest.
119 silly tarball no local data for nan@2.8.0. Extracting by manifest.
120 silly tarball no local data for epoll@1.0.2. Extracting by manifest.
121 silly tarball no local data for blynk-library@0.5.1. Extracting by manifest.
122 silly tarball no local data for onoff@1.2.0. Extracting by manifest.
123 timing audit submit Completed in 2515ms
124 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 2519ms
125 timing audit body Completed in 55ms
126 silly extract bindings@1.2.1 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/bindings-f29b19a0 (2134ms)
127 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/-/bindings-1.3.1.tgz 2038ms
128 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/epoll/-/epoll-1.0.2.tgz 1998ms
129 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/blynk-library/-/blynk-library-0.5.1.tgz 1978ms
130 silly extract bindings@1.3.1 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/bindings-6d32fc31 (2493ms)
131 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-2.8.0.tgz 2671ms
132 silly extract blynk-library@0.5.1 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/blynk-library-d777a2f0 (3134ms)
133 silly extract epoll@1.0.2 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/epoll-66440cc3 (3510ms)
134 silly extract nan@2.4.0 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/nan-9be4f48a (4150ms)
135 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/onoff/-/onoff-1.2.0.tgz 3872ms
136 silly extract nan@2.8.0 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/nan-5312de16 (4547ms)
137 silly extract pigpio@0.4.0 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/pigpio-3c408b80 (4550ms)
138 silly extract onoff@1.2.0 extracted to /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging/onoff-5e79b3e7 (4649ms)
139 timing action:extract Completed in 4725ms
140 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 64
141 silly doSerial remove 64
142 silly doSerial move 64
143 silly doSerial finalize 64
144 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/bindings
145 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/nan
146 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/epoll
147 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules/bindings
148 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules/nan
149 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/blynk-library
150 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/onoff
151 silly finalize /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio
152 timing action:finalize Completed in 244ms
153 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 8
154 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/bindings
155 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/nan
156 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/epoll
157 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules/bindings
158 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules/nan
159 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/blynk-library
160 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/onoff
161 silly refresh-package-json /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio
162 timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 423ms
163 silly doParallel preinstall 8
164 silly preinstall bindings@1.3.1
165 info lifecycle bindings@1.3.1~preinstall: bindings@1.3.1
166 silly preinstall nan@2.8.0
167 info lifecycle nan@2.8.0~preinstall: nan@2.8.0
168 silly preinstall epoll@1.0.2
169 info lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~preinstall: epoll@1.0.2
170 silly preinstall bindings@1.2.1
171 info lifecycle bindings@1.2.1~preinstall: bindings@1.2.1
172 silly preinstall nan@2.4.0
173 info lifecycle nan@2.4.0~preinstall: nan@2.4.0
174 silly preinstall blynk-library@0.5.1
175 info lifecycle blynk-library@0.5.1~preinstall: blynk-library@0.5.1
176 silly preinstall onoff@1.2.0
177 info lifecycle onoff@1.2.0~preinstall: onoff@1.2.0
178 silly preinstall pigpio@0.4.0
179 info lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~preinstall: pigpio@0.4.0
180 timing action:preinstall Completed in 15ms
181 silly doSerial build 64
182 silly build bindings@1.3.1
183 info linkStuff bindings@1.3.1
184 silly linkStuff bindings@1.3.1 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
185 silly build nan@2.8.0
186 info linkStuff nan@2.8.0
187 silly linkStuff nan@2.8.0 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
188 silly build epoll@1.0.2
189 info linkStuff epoll@1.0.2
190 silly linkStuff epoll@1.0.2 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
191 silly build bindings@1.2.1
192 info linkStuff bindings@1.2.1
193 silly linkStuff bindings@1.2.1 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules as its parent node_modules
194 silly build nan@2.4.0
195 info linkStuff nan@2.4.0
196 silly linkStuff nan@2.4.0 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules as its parent node_modules
197 silly build blynk-library@0.5.1
198 info linkStuff blynk-library@0.5.1
199 silly linkStuff blynk-library@0.5.1 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
200 verbose linkBins [ { 'blynk-client': 'bin/blynk-client.js',
200 verbose linkBins     'blynk-ctrl': 'bin/blynk-ctrl.js' },
200 verbose linkBins   '/home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.bin',
200 verbose linkBins   false ]
201 silly build onoff@1.2.0
202 info linkStuff onoff@1.2.0
203 silly linkStuff onoff@1.2.0 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
204 silly build pigpio@0.4.0
205 info linkStuff pigpio@0.4.0
206 silly linkStuff pigpio@0.4.0 has /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules as its parent node_modules
207 timing action:build Completed in 88ms
208 silly doSerial global-link 64
209 silly doParallel update-linked 0
210 silly doSerial install 64
211 silly install bindings@1.3.1
212 info lifecycle bindings@1.3.1~install: bindings@1.3.1
213 silly install nan@2.8.0
214 info lifecycle nan@2.8.0~install: nan@2.8.0
215 silly install epoll@1.0.2
216 info lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: epoll@1.0.2
217 verbose lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
218 verbose lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/epoll/node_modules/.bin:/home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
219 verbose lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: CWD: /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/epoll
220 silly lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node-gyp rebuild' ]
221 silly lifecycle epoll@1.0.2~install: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
222 silly install bindings@1.2.1
223 info lifecycle bindings@1.2.1~install: bindings@1.2.1
224 silly install nan@2.4.0
225 info lifecycle nan@2.4.0~install: nan@2.4.0
226 silly install blynk-library@0.5.1
227 info lifecycle blynk-library@0.5.1~install: blynk-library@0.5.1
228 silly install onoff@1.2.0
229 info lifecycle onoff@1.2.0~install: onoff@1.2.0
230 silly install pigpio@0.4.0
231 info lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: pigpio@0.4.0
232 verbose lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
233 verbose lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio/node_modules/.bin:/home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
234 verbose lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: CWD: /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/pigpio
235 silly lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node-gyp rebuild' ]
236 silly lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
237 info lifecycle pigpio@0.4.0~install: Failed to exec install script
238 timing action:install Completed in 36781ms
239 verbose unlock done using /home/pi/.npm/_locks/staging-654f2c7af40241aa.lock for /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock/node_modules/.staging
240 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 332ms
241 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 44552ms
242 silly saveTree test-blynk@1.0.0
242 silly saveTree ├── blynk-library@0.5.1
242 silly saveTree ├─┬ onoff@1.2.0
242 silly saveTree │ └─┬ epoll@1.0.2
242 silly saveTree │   ├── bindings@1.3.1
242 silly saveTree │   └── nan@2.8.0
242 silly saveTree └─┬ pigpio@0.4.0
242 silly saveTree   ├── bindings@1.2.1
242 silly saveTree   └── nan@2.4.0
243 warn test-blynk@1.0.0 No repository field.
244 verbose stack Error: pigpio@0.4.0 install:`node-gyp rebuild
`244 verbose stack Exit status 1
244 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
244 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
244 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
244 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
244 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
244 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
245 verbose pkgid pigpio@0.4.0
246 verbose cwd /home/pi/Smartphone-Doorlock
247 verbose Linux 4.19.58-v7+
248 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
249 verbose node v10.0.0
250 verbose npm  v6.10.2
251 error code ELIFECYCLE
252 error errno 1
253 error pigpio@0.4.0 install:`node-gyp rebuild
`253 error Exit status 1
254 error Failed at the pigpio@0.4.0 install script.
254 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
255 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Comment: Any chance we would be able to see that logging output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3YHyvp3e